# How to Pause the timer on window blur and resume the timer on window focus event?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Thanks for seeing my question.
I am using wp-pro-quiz plugin for quiz. I want to know that how can I pause the timer if the window is not in focus or is blur and resume it when it is back to focus.? 
My code:
I get reset when it get focused

```
var timelimit = (function () {
var _counter = config.timelimit;
var _intervalId = 0;
var instance = {};

instance.stop = function () {
    if (_counter) {
        window.clearInterval(_intervalId);
        globalElements.timelimit.hide();
    }
};

instance.start = function () {
    var x;
    var beforeTime;
    if (!_counter)
        return;
    var $timeText = globalElements.timelimit.find('span').text(plugin.methode.parseTime(_counter));
    var $timeDiv = globalElements.timelimit.find('.wpProQuiz_progress');

    globalElements.timelimit.show();
    $.winFocus(function (event) {
        console.log("Blur\t\t", event);
    },
    function (event) {
        console.log("Focus\t\t", event);
        x = _counter * 1000;
        beforeTime = +new Date();
    });

    _intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {

        var diff = (+new Date() - beforeTime);
        var elapsedTime = x - diff;

        if (diff >= 500) {
            $timeText.text(plugin.methode.parseTime(Math.ceil(elapsedTime / 1000)));
        }

        $timeDiv.css('width', (elapsedTime / x * 100) + '%');

        if (elapsedTime <= 0) {
            instance.stop();
            plugin.methode.finishQuiz(true);
        }

    }, 16);
};

return instance;

})();
```

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Answer (score 0):

Use this wrapper function to pause, resume your timeout.

```
var Timer;

Timer = function(callback, delay) {
  var remaining, start, timerId;
  timerId = void 0;
  start = void 0;
  remaining = delay;
  this.pause = function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timerId);
    remaining -= new Date - start;
  };
  this.resume = function() {
    start = new Date;
    window.clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
  };
  this.resume();
};
```

Intialize it like this, `timer = new Timer("callback_function_here", 45000)` 
In this case total time is 45 seconds for the callback and upon event triggers(blur or focus in your case) it will pause or resume the timer accordingly.

```
timer.pause() //pause the timer
timer.resume() //resume the timer
```

P.S - Use this function as per the logic of your code. You will have to make the timer calls accordingly in your code

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

> ```
> var time0 ; var setTimeout_Int;  var focused = true; var resume_Fun ;
> var addTime =0; var addTimeDiff =0;
>
>
> window.onfocus = function()  {
> focused = true;
> var d = new Date();
> addTimeDiff = addTimeDiff +(  d.getTime() - addTime );
> resume_Fun(); 
> }; 
>
> window.onblur = function() 
> {
>   focused = false; 
> };
>     
> function init()
> {
>   var d = new Date();
>   time0 = d.getTime(); 
>   setTimeout_Int = setTimeout(update, 1000 )
> }
>
> function update()
> {
>   clearTimeout(setTimeout_Int);
>   var d = new Date();
>   
>
>   if(focused)
>   { 
>      if(d.getTime() -(time0+addTimeDiff) < 20000)
>     {
>       setTimeout_Int= setTimeout(update, 1000 ) 
>     }
>   }
>   else 
>   {
>     addTime  =   d.getTime();
>     resume_Fun = update;
>   }
>
> }
>
> init();
> ```